# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' to type 'System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse'?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm implementing a drag and drop wpf application and i have created 3 ellipse, i'm using thumb control to drag and drop the ellipse in the map, and i wish to get the drop position for ellipse. However i get an error when drag ellipse as below:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' to type
>   'System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse'

My XAML:

```
 <Window x:Class="DragandDropMFP.MainWindow"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DragandDropMFP"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
                Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid x:Name="maingrid" MouseMove="MainGrid_MouseMove">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Map/Capture.Png" />
        </Grid.Background>


        <Canvas>
            <Thumb Canvas.Left="38" Canvas.Top="22" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta">
                <Thumb.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Viewbox Width="50" Height="50">
                            <Grid Width="20" Height="20">
                                <Ellipse 
                                 Fill="Blue"
                                 MouseMove="DragMouseMove"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Printer1" FontSize="4" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Thumb.Template>
            </Thumb>


            <Thumb Canvas.Left="37" Canvas.Top="100" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta">
                <Thumb.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Viewbox Width="50" Height="50">
                            <Grid Width="20" Height="20">
                                <Ellipse Fill="Yellow"
                                 MouseMove="DragMouseMove"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Printer2" FontSize="4" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Thumb.Template>
            </Thumb>


            <Thumb Canvas.Left="37" Canvas.Top="174" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta">
                <Thumb.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Viewbox Width="50" Height="50">
                            <Grid Width="20" Height="20">
                                <Ellipse Fill="Red"
                                 MouseMove="DragMouseMove"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Printer3" FontSize="4" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Thumb.Template>
            </Thumb>
        </Canvas>

        <TextBlock x:Name="ctlStatus" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="30" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="status" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RenderTransformOrigin="0.495,-4.7" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My xaml.cs :

```
  public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       private void MainGrid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            objmoveposition(sender, e);
        }

        private void DragMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Hand;
            objmoveposition(sender, e);
        }

        private void objmoveposition(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                if (Mouse.OverrideCursor == Cursors.Hand)
                {
                    Ellipse objTextbox = (Ellipse)sender; <--Error

                if (objTextbox != null)
                    {
                    //----< Move Control >---- 
                    Point mousePoint = e.GetPosition(this);

                    //< Vertical > 
                    int posY = (int)mousePoint.Y;
                    int actHeight = (int)Application.Current.MainWindow.Height;
                    int margin_Bottom = actHeight - (posY + (int)objTextbox.Height + (int)SystemParameters.CaptionHeight + (int)SystemParameters.BorderWidth + 4);


                    //< Horizontal > 
                    int posX = (int)mousePoint.X;
                    int actWidth = (int)Application.Current.MainWindow.Width;
                    int margin_Right = actWidth - (posX + (int)objTextbox.Width + (int)SystemParameters.BorderWidth);


                    ctlStatus.Text = "Top=" + posY + " margin_bottom=" + margin_Bottom + " WinHeigth=" + actHeight + Environment.NewLine + " Left=" + posX + " margin_Right=" + margin_Right + "WinWidth=" + actWidth;
                    //ctlStatus.Text = "position=" + objTextbox.ActualHeight;
                }
             }

            }


        }


        private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            UIElement thumb = e.Source as UIElement;

            Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange);
            Canvas.SetTop(thumb, Canvas.GetTop(thumb) + e.VerticalChange);
        }
```

Output:
[image]

Your guidance is highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: you need to determine which Ellipse is right under the cursor, instead of hard-coding it as one of the Ellipses.

Comment: look into the Thumb control - it's exactly what you are looking for if you want to implement drag&drop...

Comment: @PhilipW this is Awesome!! It's even simpler than what i have implemented now! Great info from you! Thanks many!! By the way, do you know anyway to save the drag and drop position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out by changing the Ellipse to Grid and everything works like cham..

```
Ellipse objTextbox = (Ellipse)sender;
```

change to

```
Grid objTextbox = (Grid)sender;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `sender` is the ellipse that raised the event, so you can replace this:

```
Ellipse objTextbox = ellipse1;
```

with this;

```
Ellipse objTextbox = (Ellipse)sender;
```

As long as you only assign the event to ellipses this is safe. If it gets assigned to other object types you'll need to check the type of sender before casting.

You don't need the name of the object.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, i've tried it out and get error below when i start drag the ellipse shape:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' to type 'System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse'

Comment: @Edward that's because the sender isn't an Ellipse. Without seeing your actual code I can't say what's going on. Unfortunately, SO isn't built to facilitate extended debugging.

Comment: thanks mate, i have found out the solution. And your tips is helpful!